# Characteristic function problem

Tags: characteristic-functions

first time poster so be nice!
Here's the problem:

Let $\phi(t)$ be a characteristic function, then $e^{\lambda(\phi(t)-1)}$ is a characteristic function.

Pretty stuck, any help appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Poisson distribution. Now it would be much better if you added your thoughts on the problem (and if the answer is "none", something is not right...).

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\phi(t)$ is CF of $Y$. Suppose $X=Y_1+...+Y_P$, sum of $P$ i.i.d. $Y_i$'s, where $P$ follows Poisson distribution of parameter $\lambda$. Then we have:
$$
\mathbb E(e^{itX})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb E(e^{itX};P=k)\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi(t)^k \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}=e^{\lambda(\phi(t)-1)}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Arash! Much appreciated